# Facebook App Invites iOS v4 SDK error

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I've double checked everything, from my understanding this is all I need to do:

```
self.inviteContent = [[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] initWithAppLinkURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebsite.com"]];
[FBSDKAppInviteDialog showWithContent:self.inviteContent delegate:self];
```

On mywebsite.com I have this in the heading (example values shown here):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Website</title>
    <meta property="al:ios:url" content="appurl://action">
    <meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="1234567">
    <meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="My App">
</head>
<body>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

So the dialog switches over the to the latest Facebook iOS app. I write a message and pick the person I want to send the invite to, hit send and I get this error:

```
Missing App Link URL
The app link used with this invite does not contain an Android or iOS URL. Developers are required to enter a URL for at least one platform.
```

What am I doing wrong?

My app handles the custom URL fine because if I enter `appurl://action` in Mobile Safari it opens my app up.

Comment: You can plug your url into the URL debugger tool to see if it has any invalid tags: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: Ah okay I had used that. Didn't know if the App Link stuff would show up in there. It turns out I had a og:url which was forwarding it to another url which didn't have the al tags. All sorted thanks

Comment: nice, this solved it for me as well, please convert to answer and accept!

Comment: actually no i could not solve my problem, I'm trying to invite friends on my ios game, shouldn't I share the itunes store link of my game? :/ me noob

Comment: @jdelaune can you post a copy of the finished app url?

Comment: Did you ever get this solved? I'm having problem with my URL. in debug tool FB doesn't show any errors for my URL

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to create an `AppLink` URL [from here](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=app-links-host)/

1. Choose your application from the list
2. Fill up the form with equivalent information
3. Click on Next !
4. You're done.

Now, you can use that link with your code for invite.

```
self.inviteContent = [[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] initWithAppLinkURL:[NSURL URLWithString:APP_LINK_HERE]];
[FBSDKAppInviteDialog showWithContent:self.inviteContent delegate:self];
```

The format of that link will be something like `https://fb.me/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

All `x`s will be replace by a digit.

Comment: The guy wanted to host his own app link

Comment: I am done with these steps but again i am getting the same error."Missing App Link URL
The app link used with this invite does not contain an Android or iOS URL. Developers are required to enter a URL for at least one platform."

Comment: Hey Hemang, i already did what u have showned but i didnt get any results.
 I can see the FBSDKInvite dailog and i can select friends to invite and the invite also sent successfully but my friends wont get any invites. and also im getting nil in invite delegate results

Comment: Hey @veereshkumbar, it's been a long time since I went through this case. I no longer remember about the solution to help you further. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add also og:title and og:type properties, it works for me

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My App" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
```

Comment: hey igor where to add these 2 lines.. from so many days i am searching for this kind of code for my app where i can find this code and how i can edit.. please let me know.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding meta tags would solve this, this is snippet of html from app link created via FB. Fb is adding some extra meta tags on it's app link url page, and it also redirects direct to itunes if opened on a browser.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>app name</title>
 <meta property="fb:app_id" content="your fb app id" />
 <meta property="al:ios:url" content="Your app link url" />
 <meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="your app name" />
 <meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="your app id" />
 <meta property="al:web:should_fallback" content="false" />
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/redirectToContent?id=your app store id" />
</head>
<body>
 Redirecting...
</body>
</html>
```