# FBSDKAppInviteContent for invite the Facebook friend

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-sdk-4.0

When i am using FBSDKAppInviteContent it shows an error **Missing App link url**. Kindly suggest how can i remove this and to make a dummy app link for testing.

Comment: please search before post any question. visit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30389184/1280373

Comment: But, how to make the app link url i don't understand the form.

Comment: there is clearly said with link create link